# How to write an ANTLR4 grammar for JSON objects

Tags: json, antlr4, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to write an ANTLR4 grammar for abstract data structures.  As an example consider a Python program that reads and writes a list of people, where a person has a name, email address, and phone number.  The same abstract data structure (a Python list of dicts) can be stored in multiple formats, a csv file with one person per row, a JSON file with a list of objects, an XML file, etc, but I'll start with just [JSON](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/json/JSON.g4).

```
grammar People;
import JSON;

people: person+;
person: name email phone?;
name:   STRING;
email:  STRING;
phone:  STRING;
```

The JSON grammar defines the seven `value` types, and people and person define my abstract types, but its not obvious how to link them together without forcing the grammar to be JSON-specific.

Question: assuming there are three codec grammars (JSON, CSV, XML) that define the value types array, obj, and STRING, how does a grammar specify that people is an array of person, and person is an obj of three named STRINGS?

Edit:

To clarify, I want to read a JSON instance: [{"name": "Fred", "email": "fred@foo.com"}] into a Python object defined by the ANTLR grammar, rejecting data that is valid JSON but not a valid `people` object.  And translate that object into a CSV file by just `import`ing a different codec grammar:  "Name, Email, Phone \n Fred, fred@foo.com".   I also want to use the same grammar to generate both a JSON Schema that validates JSON instances of the people list, and an XSD file that validates XML instances of the people list.

In other words, I want to know if ANTLR is capable of doing the identical thing that ASN.1 does - define the structure of data objects independently of the serialization of those objects.  And if so, learn how ANTLR represents the interface between structure and encoding/serialization.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question

Comment: This is an [X/Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) you are trying to re-create something like the Jackson Mapper library. ANTLR will not help you with that.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, it seems that what you are really looking for is a model for binding data to/from Objects, similar to how Jackson works in Java. If so, validation of structure can be gained as side-effect of trying to bind/map structure in self-describing (json, xml, csv to some degree) into programming language Object definition.
I assume such tools exist in Python (assuming that's your platform).

As others have pointed out, grammar-based parsers like ANTLR really don't seem to be something one would usually use to solve the problem.

Aside from data-binding tools, another class of utilities would be schema languages and validators, but the problem there is that they tend to only work for specific data format, so you'd have XML Schema, JSON Schema and so on. It may be possible to use for other similar formats, but even seemingly similar ones (XML, JSON) often have significant differences in logical data models.

Comment: My goal was to find a schema definition language that would work with multiple data formats, not necessarily tools that would do the translation tasks listed in the question.  If the language exists, the tools can be developed.  Aside from ASN.1 the only possibility I had was an ORM (Django's models.py or schemas derived from it).  But a python module or a file of SQL CREATE TABLE commands is not a general-purpose schema language.  I hoped that ANTLR's grammar could be adapted to that purpose, but alas, no.  I like ASN.1 but many are afraid of it, so I wanted alternatives.  ASN.1 it is.

Comment: There are a few schema languages that theoretically could work; WebIDL at some point looked like possible usable; Thrift IDL is somewhat generic; one could perhaps even consider protoc (from protobuf) or even Avro Schema. And of course some have attempted to use XML/JSON Schema with some success. No obvious cross-language choice, however.

Answer (score 2):

**This is not what ANTLR does**.

### TL;DR

ANTLR processes a grammar and generates code to parse that grammar in a target language.

***That is all it does.***

---

It does not do serialization or deserialization or mapping or anything else. It just does what is stated above.

It is tightly bound to parsing the representation, not the other way around. ANTLR is extremely popular, if it did this kind of thing there would be dozens of examples of how to do it and there would be some ubiquitous standard that you could just use. Those do not exist because that is not what the tool does.

If you want to create some new *binding* language, you could do that with ANTLR, but you will **never** get an ANTLR syntax that can read any format and map it to some arbitrary structure, **that is not what it is designed to do**, it will never do that, you are trying to use the wrong tool for the wrong job.

ANTLR is a parser writer, you can write a JSON parser or a CSV parser or an XML parser, but you can't write a grammar file that will convert all of those to some generic object representation.

You can parse ANS.1 with ANTLR just fine, but it does not do anything else.

JAXB exists to de/serialize XML to and from objects with an *optional* schema.

Jackson exists to de/serialized JSON, XML, CSV, YAML, Protocol Buffers, etc to and from objects with an *optional* serialization specific schema.

ASN.1 does not do what you are asking either, it just defines a *schema* that is serialization independent, it does **not** do any parsing or validation. You are conflating tools that read and process ASN.1 with the specification of the language syntax.

It is just a schema standard. Some independent parser parses the specific serialization scheme than some imperative program reads the ASN.1 and applies its rules.

JSON Schema exists to define JSON documents,
XML schema and DTD before it exists to define XML documents.
CSV has a header row. All are just specifications on language syntax, specialized for a reason none of them actually do anything.

Comment: Please cite the text that leads you to think: "You are conflating tools that read and process ASN.1 with the specification.".   I said: "I want to know if ANTLR is capable of doing the identical thing that ASN.1 does - define the structure of data objects independently of the serialization of those objects".   ANTLR is a grammar and tools, ASN.1 is a grammar and tools.  The question is clearly not "can a grammar process data".   The short answer to the question asked is: "ANTLR (grammar and tools) cannot express data abstraction".